# Passing Location object between Android activities

Tags: android, location

I have a Location object which I would like to pass to another activity.
I read how you can pass custom objects using Serialization but how to pass predefined objects.
One solution could be to create a custom class with only the Location variable. Is there some other way ?

Comment: then use parcel method

Comment: Why do you want to pass the whole location object, just pass the lat/long as double values in the intent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like [@nongthonbam-tonthoi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4094260/nongthonbam-tonthoi) offered:
A Location is defined by 3 values: Latitude , Longitude and Accuracy (essentially a dot + radius).

```
Location loc = getLocationFromSomewhere();
Data myData = new Data.Builder()
    .putDouble(KEY_LOC_LAT, loc.getLatitude())
    .putDouble(KEY_LOC_LON, loc.getLongitude())
    .putDouble(KEY_LOC_ACCURACY, loc.getAccuracy())
    .build();

OneTimeWorkRequest myWork = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker.class)
        .setInputData(myData)
        .build();
WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(myWork);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can convert to json string and then post it to other activity

use this library
[gson](https://github.com/google/gson)

and this code for convert

```
String pLocation = new Gson().toJson(mLocation);
```